# Methods with optional and keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

```
def test(a, b = {}, c: 1)
  [a, b, c]
end

test 1, {hello: :world}
```

I would expect the output of this to be:

```
[1, {hello: :word}, 1]
```

But instead I got:

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: hello
```

I've read some pages like https://makandracards.com/makandra/36011-ruby-do-not-mix-optional-and-keyword-arguments

that suggest to dont mix with optional arguments a keywords argument.

Is possible to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this exact signature, you should probably use double-splat for `b` parameter:

```
def test(a, c: 1, **b)
  [a, b, c]
end
test 1, {hello: :world}
#⇒ [1, {hello: :word}, 1]
```

There are issues distinguishing named keyword parameters and the hash itself when the latter is passed immediately before named keywords.

Comment: If you pass a Hash containing non-Symbol keys, your method will blow up with an `ArgumentError` instead of passing the Hash to `b`. This is because keyword arguments always have to be given with Symbol keys.

Comment: @HolgerJust true, so what?

Comment: With that, I just wanted to say that your solution doesn't completely fulfil the desired interface for all arguments. With respect to the tradeoffs involved, it is a good solution though. In any case, if OP only passes Hashes containing non-Symbol keys to `b`, his method definition will work directly.